# HTML Table of Acronyms - show meaning on mouseover

Tags: css, css-tables

I have a HTML Table with 2 columns and about 80 rows, which contains Acronyms, and their meanings.

Is there a (CSS?) way to display just the first row of the table, and have the meaning (i.e. it's accompanying td in the same tr) come up in some sort of box on mouseover?

Comment: Probably ... what have you found out in your research, what have you tried?

Comment: Nothing as yet, I've just started looking, its straight-forwards with single items with JS but ive not done this to a whole table before.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked before, but yes. You can.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e75cxdn6/)

CSS:

```
.meaning {
  display:none;
}
.Acronym:hover + .meaning {
  display:unset;  
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr><td class="Acronym">Foo</td><td class="meaning">bar</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="Acronym">Foo2</td><td class="meaning">bar2</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That looks nice and simple - Thank you!

Comment: Note that this only works if the `meaning` follows the `acronym`. That is, you can only select following siblings like this. It doesn't work for a previous sibling, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with only css using the `:hover` selector.

Here is an example of a cell with a tooltip, each `.cell` can be a `<td>` in a table.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/kyleperik/pen/qXwjgv)

html

```
<span class="cell">
  acr.
  <div class="tooltip">Acronym</div>
</span>
```

css

```
.cell {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.cell .tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 250ms;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 2px;
}

.cell:hover .tooltip {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question, because it requires the meanings to be *inside* the acronym's `td`, whereas OP has the meanings in an adjacent `td`.

Comment: It doesn't actually solve my EXACT question, but with a bit of find & replace it allows a better UI/UX than just showing/hiding the meaning td.

Comment: Fair enough. Good luck, and don't forget to accept the answer of your choice.